# Debounce from lodash is not working in my app

Tags: reactjs, lodash

Like the title says, debounce functionality from library called lodash is not working my app. I am using it to optimize search functionality in my app. Let me precisely describe you how is my code structured. In one component called Users.js I have implemented the search functionality, and then through the use of props I am sending the searchValue, as well as onChange function that allows for the search to work.

When I use debounce with that onChange function it doesn't want to work. Here is my code for better understanding:

```
const Users = () => {
  const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users?page=`;
  const searchUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users?name=`;

  const cellNames = [
    {
      name: "User Names",
      paddingRight: 230,
      paddingLeft: 40,
    },
    {
      name: "Email",
    },
    {
      name: "Status",
    },
    {
      name: "Gender",
    },
    {
      name: "Role",
    },
    {
      name: "Actions",
      align: "center",
      paddingRight: 40,
    },
  ];

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const debouncedHandleSearch = useMemo(() => debounce(handleSearch, 300), []);

  return (
    <Layout
      title="Users - Admin View"
      hasSearchBox={true}
      searchValue={searchValue}
      onChange={debouncedHandleSearch}
    >
      <LinkContainer>
        <CreateUserLink
          to={{
            pathname: "/users/new",
          }}
        >
          <CreateButton variant="filled" text="CREATE USER" />
        </CreateUserLink>
      </LinkContainer>
      <TableContainer data-testid="users-table">
        <TableComponent
          url={url}
          cellNames={cellNames}
          value={searchValue}
          searchUrl={searchUrl}
        />
      </TableContainer>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

This is Users.js component.

```
import React from "react";
import Searchbox from "Components/Searchbox";
import styled from "styled-components";

const LayoutContainer = styled.div`
  margin-left: 3.625em;
  margin-right: 4.5625rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
`;

const TopLayoutContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 2.5rem;
`;

const Layout = ({ title, hasSearchBox, children, searchValue, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <LayoutContainer>
      <TopLayoutContainer>
        <Title>{title}</Title>
        {hasSearchBox ? (
          <Searchbox value={searchValue} onChange={onChange} />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </TopLayoutContainer>
      {children}
    </LayoutContainer>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

This is Layout.js, this component as you can see has prop called onChange, and that is how I am sending that search function to this component. Also if you notice, the searchbox is a component, here is how it looks like:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import React from "react";
import Input from "Components/Input";

const SearchInput = styled(Input)``;

const Container = styled.div``;

const Searchbox = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <SearchInput
        data-testid="searchbox-component"
        placeholder="Search..."
        type="Search"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Searchbox;
```

I genuinely don't know why is this not working, if anyone knows any solution I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't `useMemo(() => debounce(handleSearch, 300), []);` be `useMemo(debounce(handleSearch, 300), []);`?

Comment: I get an error saying "e is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work since you keep the value of input debounce.

To fix it, you need two state: the first one to keep the typing value, the second one to keep the debounced value.

Passing the typing value into input, and the debounced value to your search api (or something you need debounced).

[Checkout this sandbox to experiment](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-shadow-4noih?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, this is working, any chance you know how to make this as a custom hook?

Comment: Yes, you can make a custom hook by extracting two state and the handleChange logic.

Comment: Do you have any code that I can see, I am really struggling to do this as a custom hook, if you do I would appreciate that

Comment: Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-currying-t6o00?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: It's working, thank you again, you helped me a lot.